# R - Control the color and size of one specific group of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data, control plus 4 experiment. I'm hoping to emphasize the control group data in ggplot. I have put data of control group in df_control, and the rest of data in df_lead.

Here's my code:

```
    plot_lead <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(df_control, mapping = aes(CollectDate, ReportedResult, size = 0.7), show.legend = 
    TRUE) + 
    geom_point(df_control, mapping = aes(CollectDate, ReportedResult), show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_line(df_lead, mapping = aes(CollectDate, ReportedResult, group = Site, color = Site))) +
    geom_point(df_lead, mapping = aes(CollectDate, ReportedResult, group = Site, color = Site))) +
    scale_x_date(name = "", date_breaks = "2 week", date_labels = "%Y/%m/%d") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Pb, mg/L") +
    theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16, 
                          face = "bold",
                          family = "sans",
                          color = "black",
                          hjust = 0.5,
                          lineheight = 1.2 ), # Title
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="plain", size=10.5, angle=90), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="plain", size=10.5, angle=0), 
    legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black'), 
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey")
    )
```

Here's a short set of data:
        df_control:

```
    Site        CollectDate   Param   ReportedResult
    Control      2019-06-17    Lead    0.6 
    Control      2019-06-23    Lead    0.3
    Control      2019-07-02    Lead    1.3
    Control      2019-07-10    Lead    0.4
    Control      2019-07-17    Lead    2.3

    df_lead:
    Site        CollectDate   Param   ReportedResult
    1            2019-06-18    Lead    0.3 
    1            2019-06-22    Lead    0.2
    1            2019-07-01    Lead    1.5
    1            2019-07-10    Lead    0.9
    1            2019-07-16    Lead    3.1
    2            2019-06-17    Lead    1.3 
    2            2019-06-20    Lead    1.2
    2            2019-07-02    Lead    2.5
    2            2019-07-09    Lead    2.9
    2            2019-07-15    Lead    3.1     
    2            2019-07-22    Lead    3.3 
    3            2019-06-20    Lead    0.6
    3            2019-06-30    Lead    1.0
    3            2019-07-07    Lead    1.9
    3            2019-07-15    Lead    1.1
    3            2019-07-23    Lead    0.3 
    4            2019-06-22    Lead    0.4
    4            2019-07-01    Lead    0.5
    4            2019-07-10    Lead    0.9
    4            2019-07-16    Lead    1.1 
    4            2019-07-23    Lead    0.9
```

However, the name of the legend is now shown as "Size 0.7", and graph looks quite ugly - a black thick line for the control data.

How should I modify the code so that I can control the color of the site and make them distinguishable? And the legend of the control would show in the legend?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you put `size = 0.7` inside `geom_line()` but outside `aes()`, it won't show up in the legend. (Generally you should put mappings to data columns inside `aes()`, and constants outside of `aes()`.)

Comment: The other option is to keep all your data in one data frame, and map `size = Site` inside `aes()`, and then make a custom scale with `scale_size_manual` to make everything except the `"Control"`` the same size.

Comment: Thank you! I started with one df but I wasn't sure how to differentiate them so decided to use 2 df instead. Good to know that I could do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using color to differentiate from the control vs the experiment groups, but only after you join the data like Gregor Thomas suggested in the comments. The below code assumes to joined both data frames with the key being the Param, and naming the Data frame 'df'

```
 fill_colors <- c()
 for ( i in 1:length(df$Site) ) {
   if (df$Site[i] == "Control") {
     fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#821122")
   } else {
     fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#cccccc")
   }
 }
```

Comment: What if I want to have different color for different site? Would this code be inside the ggplot our outside? Thanks!

Comment: `ifelse` is a vectorized version of `if()`, so instead of a `for` loop you could do `fill_colors = ifelse(df$Site == "Control", "#821122", "#ccccc")`. (And I'm confused by your `hotdogs$Country` --- where does that come from?)

Comment: Oops, thanks Gregor, it was from another example  I have.

Comment: [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/) is a link that is all about colors for ggplot2, you would need to create this before your ggplot2 code, for colors, look at Gregor Thomas's example.